# whenever i use sudo apt-get remove/install, reply is Error

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS and whenever I use:

```
sudo apt-get remove
sudo apt-get install
```

it replies:

```
cp: failed to extend `/boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-47-generic.dpkg-bak': No space left on device
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Is this right?

Is it installing/removing?

The reply for:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

is:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Setting up initramfs-tools (0.99ubuntu13.4) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools ...
ln: failed to create hard link `/boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-47-generic.dpkg-bak' => `/boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-47-generic': Operation not permitted
cp: writing `/boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-47-generic.dpkg-bak': No space left on device
cp: failed to extend `/boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-47-generic.dpkg-bak': No space left on device
dpkg: error processing initramfs-tools (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 initramfs-tools
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: post only the output of `sudo apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your errors said:

> No space left on device

Open System Monitor from Dash and select the Filesystems tab.

[image]

And if the problem is only related to /boot partition try this:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

If it didn't work then It seems you have no space in /boot

You've a lot unused kernels. Remove all but the last kernels with:

```
sudo apt-get purge $(dpkg -l linux-{image,headers}-"[0-9]*" | awk '/ii/{print $2}' | grep -ve "$(uname -r | sed -r 's/-[a-z]+//')")
```

Comment: i got the same reply :(

Comment: @user222588 can you tell me how many space left do you have

Comment: well in /boot 0 bytes

Answer (score 1):

```
cp: failed to extend `/boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-47-generic.dpkg-bak': No space left on device
```

You have to free up the `/boot` partition.Remove all the old unused kernals.

See [How do I free up more space in /boot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/89710/how-do-i-free-up-more-space-in-boot)